# How do I get the shaded elements in a jstree checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jstree

I currently have a jstree in which I get the selection elements with the code:

```
var selectedElmsIds = [];
var selectedElms = $('#PermisosjsTree').jstree("get_selected", true);
$.each(selectedElms, function () {
    selectedElmsIds.push(this.id);
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

but I need to obtain the overlaid elements (marked with red below), how do I get them?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The 'parents' property of the node should give you the parent and its ancestors.

```
$.each(selectedElms, function () {
    selectedElmsIds.push(this.id);
    console.log(this.id);
    console.log(this.parents);
});
```